# Is  (Unicode 'pile of poo') considered NSFW?

Tags: indicator, special-characters

Can I use the  character as a legitimate status indication on, say, a web application, or in a desktop application? Or will it offend/embarrass people?

<sub>*[NSFW = "Not safe/suitable for work"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nsfw?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic), although it's also become generally used regardless of the environment (for example: public places), and speaks to a general impression given.*</sub>

Comment: Who doesn't love chocolate frozen yogurt? It's safe for work (until HR/management tells you otherwise). It's just in bad taste and would make you look unprofessional (unless you worked in waste management, or on a comedy show).

Comment: Keep in mind that many users (e.g. me) can't see that character.

Comment: Ironically, this is now a Hot Network Question and will appear whenever someone goes to Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange for work.

Comment: "…and for today's extra content we have this shit emoji. it can troll your conversations at any time, so we must deal with it."

Comment: Well, I hope this isn't NSFW, because I've just viewed it. At work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55736/discussion-on-question-by-jason-c-is--unicode-pile-of-poo-considered-nsfw).

Comment: I would say it depends on the context @Stephen Branczyk. I work for a major consumer products company that makes disposable baby diapers (as well as toilet paper). I once saw an internal presentation wherein the speaker had legitimate reason to use the smiling pile of poo emoji no less than 10 times. So in my organization, it is totally safe for work, if a little cliche. Your mileage may vary, however. Basically, every time somebody does a #2, we make money. :)

Comment: fwiw, I can't see the character.

Comment: "NSFW" often refers to material that's not even safe to view at work. The poo emoji doesn't fall into that category. However, I would personally consider use of the poo emoji *unprofessional*.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why some of the commenters do not see this emoji? I though that with a proper `Content-Type` the browser should render it correctly?

Comment: @WoJ I've actually kind of been wondering that as well. It's been in Unicode since 2010, and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the idea that, in 2017, there are enough browsers and platforms that both a) do not support at least the somewhat common symbols in Unicode 6, *and* b) are being used to view this question on UX, that it comes up in comments. I'm also curious. It's too bad "Can you see this character: " wasn't on the Developer Survey.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

## If you have to ask, it's risky (not necessarily offensive)

This doesn't mean it won't get the job done for your users and the best way to find that out is ask a few of them and gauge their reaction.

## Something delightful may quickly turn annoying

Keep in mind that just because something delights users when they first encounter it doesn't mean it will stay delightful on subsequent visits.  This is especially true when it gets in the way of getting their task accomplished.

## There is usually more than one solution

Consider what you're trying to communicate and see if there is a more universal way to say it.

Look for a solution which doesn't cater to one persona over another.  In the case of a poo emoji you could communicate the same sentiment with the frown or angry (or possibly ice cream?) emoji.

Comment: This is pretty much the main point to think about: ***"If you have to ask, it's risky"***. If you need to think twice then it's clearly something you're unsure of and thus there is a reason for your uncertainty of using said emoji. After all, it is a ***smiling pile of poo*** according to Apple's text to speech feature.

Comment: @DanielJames I see I'm a mere mortal compared to Apple's text to speech engineers. No matter how hard I look, I can't tell whether that pile of poo is smiling.

Comment: "Something delightful may quickly turn" - When I was first learning Javascript, I found something simple to test out my skills. I took the "Loading, please wait" on long running reports to have a small list of more creative phrases. Most thought it was cool. One person actually called my boss and was pretty upset about it. Note that this screen already had a dancing banana gif... so to this day I'm still not sure how the messages (which were all in good taste, admittedly so by Mr. Grumpy) were a bad thing...

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev and DanielJames, Apple renders the emoji with a smiling face.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev i bet that is a special case where they hardcoded that Unicode to that text. No engineering at all besides an entry into a static table. The "smiling" part is probably an attempt at making it less *smelly*.

Comment: @Mindwin So the Apple engineer mis-heard "smelly pile of poo" and wrote it as "smiley pile of poo"?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy I also bet that if you think outside the box about that, you will come to the conclusion that poo would sell better if it was smiling rather than smelling. [history channel guy]: "marketing".

Comment: "parallax scrolling on web pages was delightful at first but quickly became annoying since the windows scroll thumb designed for navigating pages of content was being hijacked as a video scrubber" Is this the thing where "parallax scrolling" is constantly misused by authors to refer to something that actually has no relation to parallax scrolling whatsoever? That's what I glean from the term "video scrubber", at least. Because actual parallax scrolling doesn't hijack the scrolling mechanism to do something it wasn't intended for - it visually *augments* scrolling, and is usually non-intrusive.

Comment: Oops, wrong answer. Meant to comment on the post.

Comment: I felt the parallax example was a distraction and opted to remove it from the answer.  Like anything else it can be used properly or improperly.  The point is to be aware the first time a user sees something and is delighted doesn't mean they will have the same feeling on subsequent visits.

Answer (score 70):

I would suggest that it isn't necessarily *offensive* but *juvenile*, so it very much depends on the style, context and audience of your app.

## Culture

Ask yourself if the app is available worldwide? I can only speak with authority about my own culture, which may be different than others.

## Context

What might be totally inappropriate for a retirement savings website might be good fun in a mobile chat app.

On the other hand, I know a (very serious) medical lab that deals with stool samples. They use this emoji internally to disarm otherwise awkward discussions. " Remember your PPE!"

In other words, I would say it's *safe* from an NSFW perspective, but you'll have to decide if it's *appropriate*.

Comment: I cringe with embarrassment for the person that is using this emoji.

Comment: Yes, well, it has its moments.

Comment: The *Culture* section in your answer involuntarily made me wonder whether the depicted pile of poo is culture-specific and might not be recognized for what it is in some regions of the world.

Comment: PPE stands for Personal Protective Equipment, i.e. gloves, face shields, dust masks, etc. @BaileyS absolutely agree in nearly all cases, but this is a rare alignment-of-the-stars, as the icon *literally* displays fecal matter, which is one reason for PPE.

Comment: I'm waiting for the follow up question: "What does mean to you?"

Comment: @Harper My cringe was informed on the definition of PPE.  It still seems garish, and perhaps a bit trite.

Comment: @BaileyS Well, still, you kinda have to admit that it makes an impression (humorous or not), which is a good thing given the context. Makes it hard to forget your PPE, so at least it's effective for the end goal. You know, I actually see a lot of bad / juvenile / tasteless humor regarding important safety equipment in labs and industrial contexts (e.g. there's a whole series of The Simpson's safety posters); I never thought about it before but it is an effective strategy when used sparingly (by "sparingly" I mean if *everything* is a joke then nothing stands out as memorable).

Answer (score 11):

On a Monday morning, I didn't expect to start my day with this question. I am amused and smiling and not embarrassed at all.

Having said that, it depends on the target audience and context of your application. I would definitely not use this in enterprise or professional apps as we are expected to maintain some sort of decorum in the way we design our interfaces.

At the same time, if you are building something for teenagers, or people expecting your app to have a funny, quirky and amusing way of interacting, I'd not hesitate to keep this as a status indication.

Here are a few options for escalation status icons.

, , , , ✴

The last being ' hits the fan' but I am sure you can come up with a better icon.

Comment: How about using ✽?

Comment: I would not be happy being disciplined for failing to treat an [icon] [icon] case with appropriate seriousness. I can't figure out how to type those icons on an iPad, or to be more precise, I have no reason to *want* to.  This goes double if I'm on a platform which does not support the icon and I see .

Answer (score 7):

I would classify something as NSFW when it runs the risk of creating a hostile (in the sense of discrimination, sexual harassment, etc.) environment for others you're interacting professionally with - coworkers, clients, customers, etc. I don't think the poop emoji fits this criterion. It's potentially gross, juvenile, etc. but not hostile. This may vary by culture and context, of course.

Now, whether it's suitable/good UX, which seems to be what you really want to know, is another matter, and really depends on your application's audience. The answer by cloudworks gives a great example of a unique situation in which I think it is very appropriate. Apps with casual/lighthearted purpose, which people interact with purely by choice, not because it's something they need to use to get work done, would also be candidates where you could consider its use, contingent on cultural considerations. In most contexts, though, I think it will just, well, make your app look like .

Answer (score 6):

Isn't interesting that we've invented emoticons to convey emotion that is difficult to do in text.  That said, when I read an official document or communication from a corporation, I neither expect or want to find an emoticon.

Are emoticons safe for work - sure.  Are they appropriate for official communication, probably not.  Are the appropriate for email between colleagues - probably not.

Comment: Right. It's not an NSFW question, it's a professionalism question.

Answer (score 6):

In the game Furcadia, we deliberately blocked and filtered out codepoints in the Fixedsys Excelsior 2 font which mapped to penises, poops, and other such things, as it was an app that could be used by children. This was more about the penises than the poops, though.

Still, it is arguably considered, at least by one company, as "not child safe".

Based on this, if your work could be used by children, then you could argue it is also "not work safe".

From a UX standpoint, I would recommend an icon with a more universally-understood message: in Japan, the poop emoji means "I am very sorry, I messed up". In the US, it is a funny emoji with no fixed reason.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion on the matter is that an icon like this, as a status, would represent something bad or undesirable happening. If I were a worker using this program and I encountered this problem, be it an small error or a critical failure on a hypothetical shop floor, the last thing I would want is a bit of comedy sprinkled on top of a terrible situation. So, it really depends on when you're displaying it. As an ignorant user, I might wonder something along the lines of, "Why did they take the time to put this icon here, rather than prevent the error?!"

If that makes sense.